# How many 9-digits numbers have 2,6, and 8 in whatever order?

Tags: combinatorics

The numbers will contain these digits at least once. I've tried combinations and combinations with repetitions, but none of these seem to work with smaller examples.

Comment: How many 9-digit number do not contain 2,6, and 8?

Comment: Would you accept $1=000000001$?

Comment: @DanielMathias 6*7*7*10^6?

Comment: @AndreaMori accept?

Comment: There are $6\times7^8$ 9-digit numbers that contain none of digits $(2,6,8)$. Use inclusion/exclusion to find how many other numbers do not contain all three of $(2,6,8)$

Comment: I believe Andrea is asking you if a 9 digit number can start with one or more zeros. i.e. is $1$ a 9 digit number.

Comment: @fleablood Yes because it says PINs, not  numbers. And I'm gonna try inclusion/exclusion, thanks.

Comment: Start with a simpler problem, such as same question tor 3-digit numbers. Then repeat for 4-digit numbers. Continue increasing the number of digits until you see a pattern and can solve for an n-digit number. Then make n=9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $6\cdot7^8=34588806$ 9-digit numbers containing none of the digits $(2,6,8)$

There are $7\cdot8^8=117440512$ 9-digit numbers containing neither of the digits $(2,6)$. This includes numbers that also do not contain the digit $8$. Excluding those, there are $117440512-34588806=82851706$ 9-digit numbers containing at least one $8$ but none of $2$ or $6$.

Similarly, there are $82851706$  9-digit numbers containing at least one $6$ but none of $2$ or $8$, and $82851706$  9-digit numbers containing at least one $2$ but none of $6$ or $8$

There are $8\cdot9^8=344373768$ 9-digit numbers that do not contain the digit $2$. Excluding those numbers that also do not contain $6$, $8$, or $6$ and $8$, there are $344373768-2\cdot82851706-34588806=144081550$ 9-digit numbers that do not contain the digit $2$, but do contain at least one each of $6$ and $8$.

Similarly, there are $144081550$ 9-digit numbers that do not contain the digit $6$, but do contain at least one each of $2$ and $8$ and $144081550$ 9-digit numbers that do not contain the digit $8$, but do contain at least one each of $2$ and $6$.

Adding this together we have $34588806+3\cdot82851706+3\cdot144081550=715388574$ 9-digit numbers that exclude at least one of the digits $(2,6,8)$, leaving $900000000-715388574=184611426$ 9-digit numbers that contain at least one each of the digits (2,6,8).

The final count is $184611426$, though there may be an easier way to arrive at this result.